# Managing quartz jobs, deleting

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Consider the following sequence of events. Using quartz 1.8.0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I schedule a job to be executed in the future

```
     job.setGroup(MY_GROUP);
     Date date = scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);    // Valid date received
```

**Job executes as expected.**

I then try to delete the job by running

```
     boolean unscheduled = scheduler.deleteJob(event.getName(), MY_GROUP); // Always false
```

Attempt to delete the job always results in `**false**`

If i let the application to run past the time it was scheduled to execute, after having failed to delete it, it ... does not run (as if it was deleted successfully)

**What could explain such a behavior? How can i know what is scheduled in quartz as part of the group?**

**EDIT:**

Trigger is set as:

```
        SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger();
        trigger.setStartTime(new Date(event.getStartTime().inMillis()));
        trigger.setName("trigger" + event.getTriggerName());
        trigger.setRepeatInterval(event.getFrequency());
        trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
```

Answer (score 1):

What trigger are you using?  If you haven't specified that the trigger should fire multiple times e.g. on a recurring interval, then it will only fire once and will then be discarded; if your job detail isn't durable then the scheduler will automatically remove it once no more triggers point to it.